# Proof that $\sin x + 3\sin 2x + 3\sin 3x + \sin 4x > 0$ for $ 0 < x < 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How do I solve this? I have tried factorising it but did not manage to solve it.

$\sin x + 3\sin 2x + 3\sin 3x + \sin 4x > 0$

for $ 0 < x < 2\pi$

Comment: use the addition formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\sin{x}+3\sin{2x}+3\sin{3x}+\sin{4x}=2\sin\frac{5x}{2}\cos\frac{3x}{2}+6\sin\frac{5x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}=$$
$$=2\sin\frac{5x}{2}\left(\cos\frac{3x}{2}+3\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)=8\sin\frac{5x}{2}\cos^3\frac{x}{2},$$
we get the answer:

$\frac{2\pi}{5}<x<\frac{4\pi}{5}$ or $\pi<x<\frac{6\pi}{5}$ or $\frac{8\pi}{5}<x<2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

use the formula

$$\sin(a)+\sin(b)=$$

$$2\sin( \frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

for $\sin(x)+\sin(4x)$  and for

$3(\sin(2x)+\sin(3x))$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using complex numbers.

Let $x=2y$. The given expression is the imaginary part of

$$e^{i2y}+3e^{i4y}+3e^{i6y}+e^{8y}=e^{5iy}(e^{-3iy}+3e^{-iy}+3e^{+iy}+e^{3iy})=e^{5iy}(e^{-iy}+e^{+iy})^3$$

$$=e^{5iy}(2i \sin(3y))^3=\sin^3(3y) (i^2) i e^{5iy}=-\sin^3(3y) e^{i\pi/2} e^{5iy}=-\sin^3(3y)e^{i(5y+\pi/2)}$$

whose imaginary part is:

$$-\sin^3(3y) \sin(5y+\pi/2)=-\sin^3(3y) \cos(5y)$$

whence the result by converting back in terms of variable $x$:

$$-\sin^3\left(\dfrac{3x}{2}\right) \cos\left(\dfrac{5x}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your function is the imaginary part of 
$$ e^{ix} + 3 e^{2ix} + 3 e^{3ix} + e^{4ix} = e^{ix}(e^{ix}+1)^3  = 8e^{5ix/2}\cos(x/2)^3$$
so it is $8\sin(5x/2)\cos(x/2)^3$ and its sign is straightforward to study.